# Association type mismatch in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 5.1
```

My migration file:

```
class CreateFwExports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :fw_exports, id: :string do |t|
      t.string :screen_name, index: true, limit: 16
      t.string :full_name, limit: 21
      t.string :location

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

In my helper file, I have the following method:

```
def process_spreadsheet(number_of_rows, spreadsheet)
  for i in 1..number_of_rows do
    fw_export_record = FwExport.new(
        :screen_name => spreadsheet[i][0].to_s,
        :full_name => spreadsheet[i][1].to_s,
        :location => spreadsheet[i][2].to_s,
    )
    fw_export_record.save
  end
end
```

What this method does, is receive a spreadsheet CSV object, and iterates through the data, trying to save each row to the fw_exports table.

The first data row is:

```
xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,"Nottingham, England"
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Location(#38400060) expected, got "Nottingham, England" which is an instance of String(#10657520)):
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:21:in `block in process_spreadsheet'
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:20:in `process_spreadsheet'
app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb:82:in `process_parsed_spreadsheet'
```

When I looked at the actual MySQL table, here's what I got:

```
id Primary  varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      No  None
screen_name  varchar(16)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Yes NULL
full_name   varchar(21) utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Yes NULL
location    varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      Yes NULL
```

From the controller:

```
def fw_export_params
  params.require(:fw_export).permit(:screen_name, :full_name, :location)
end
```

id is generated through a method defined in the concerns section

Any idea why I'm getting the error message?

## Edit:

In my fw_exports.rb model, I had the following:

```
has_one :location
```

I have a locations table (and model), with the following fields:

```
  t.string :fw_exports_id, index: true
  t.string :city
  t.string :state
  t.string :country
```

When I commented out, the line in the fw_exports.rb model:

```
# has_one :location
```

I stopped getting the above mentioned error, and instead, I am now getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "0":String):
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:21:in `block in process_spreadsheet'
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:20:in `process_spreadsheet'
app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb:82:in `process_parsed_spreadsheet'
```

Same spot in code, different message.

Comment: can you please share the `FwExport` model? the error strongly signals that you might have defined an association with `:location` of type `Location` inside of the model.

Comment: I was in the process of editing this question. See edit

Comment: my assumption is right! let me write an effective solution for you. you can modify it later if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have:

```
class FwExport < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location
```

and assuming that:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fw_export
```

so you cannot define `:location` as a string column in `CreateFwExports` migration.

First you need to write another migration to remove the column from `:fw_exports` table:

```
class RemoveColumnFromFwExports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_column :fw_exports, :location, :string
  end
end
```

Now rewrite the helper method that would parse the location string from csv into a `Location` instance and assign it into the `FwExport` instance:

```
def process_spreadsheet(number_of_rows, spreadsheet)
  1.upto(number_of_rows) do |i|
    fw_export_record = FwExport.new(
        screen_name: spreadsheet[i][0].to_s,
        full_name: spreadsheet[i][1].to_s,
    )
    fw_export_record.save

    # now create the location and associate it to fw_export_record
    location = find_or_create_location(spreadsheet[i][2].to_s)
    location.fw_exports_id = fw_export_record.id
    location.save
  end
end

private

def find_or_create_location(s)
  city, country = s.split(',').map(&:strip)
  Location.find_or_create_by!(city: city, country: country)
end
```

Comment: The locations table is only initially populated with the fw_exports_id field, and gets filled later, so I don't need to do the find_or_create_location. Instead, I have location_record = Location,new(fw_exports_id = fw_export_record.id) location_record.save

Comment: taking the location record out of the fw_export model, solves my initial problem, but now I have the new error: NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "0":String): as described in the edit to my question

Comment: you cannot comment out `has_one :location` in `fw_exports.rb`; its required for being able to query the location for any particular `FwExport` record.

Comment: I did not comment out has_one :location, I removed :location from the migration and model for fw_export. The question is now pretty convoluted to follow, I may repost it as another question for clarity

Comment: if you fill the location later, no problem. But you have to remove the `location` column that is defined as `:string` in `fw_exports` table, as described at the start of my solution.

Comment: pls share the new post link here if you make one.

Comment: I will re-write this later today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159013/discussion-between-eastsidedeveloper-and-wasif-hossain).

Answer (score 2):

Add `|i|` after the do

```
for i in 1..number_of_rows do |i|
```

Edit after response in comment:
You don't show the model but probably you have a relationship called `location` that is conflicting with the field.

Comment: Note: `(1..number_of_rows).each do |i|` or `1.upto(5).each do |i|` would be idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: My IDE (RubyMine) will not accept this syntax: for i in 1..number_of_rows do |i|. It did accept (1..number_of_rows).each do |i|, but I'm still getting the same error message